# Why ssh fails from crontab but succeeds when executed from a command line?

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, cron

I have a bash script that does ssh to a remote machine and executes a command there, like:

```
ssh -nxv user@remotehost echo "hello world"
```

When I execute the command from a command line it works fine, but it fails when is being executed as a part of crontab (errorcode=255 - cannot establish SSH connection). Details:

```
...
Waiting for server public key.
Received server public key and host key.
Host 'remotehost' is known and matches the XXX host key.
...
Remote: Your host key cannot be verified: unknown or invalid host key.
Server refused our host key.
Trying XXX authentication with key '...'
Server refused our key.
...
```

When executing locally I'm acting as a root, crontab works as root as well.
Executing 'id' from crontab and command line gives exactly the same result:

```
$ id
> uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),...
```

I do ssh from some local machine to the machine running crond. I have ssh key and credentials to ssh to crond machine and any other machine that the scripts connects to.

PS. Please do not ask/complain/comment that executing anything as root is bad/wrong/etc - it is not the purpose of this question.

Comment: Try with -v instead of -q --- it still won't work, but it will give you diagnostics that may help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dave! - I include interesting part of the output when executing with -v

Comment: I removed my answer due to changed facts/question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am guessing that normally when you ssh from your local machine to the machine running crond, your private key is loaded in ssh-agent and forwarded over the connection.  So when you execute the command from the command line, it finds your private key in ssh-agent and uses it to log in to the remote machine.

When crond executes the command, it does not have access to ssh-agent, so cannot use your private key.

You will have to create a new private key for root on the machine running crond, and copy the public part of it to the appropriate `authorized_keys` file on the remote machine that you want crond to log in to.

Comment: Dave, how can list keys registered in ssh-agent? That would help to actually check that case.

Comment: Try running ssh-add -l (that's dash lower-case-L).

Comment: mmmh weird this doesn't seem to be true. inside my cron script i added a simple : ssh-agent at the bottom and it seem to return a valid agent. *BUT* even with that, i can't do ssh authentications with a crontab weird ! I treid your solution but it didn't work either

Comment: by the way when i do a `whoami` in the script i do get my username not root.

Comment: @apouche `ssh-agent` doesn't return an existing agent, it tries to set up a new one.

Comment: I have samerpblem but I'm bit using ssh-agent, I'm using passwordless key-pair but still not working, any suggestion?

Comment: Don't expose your SSH keys without passphrase. Use ssh-cron instead, which allows you to schedule tasks using SSH agents. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869589/why-ssh-fails-from-crontab-but-succedes-when-executed-from-a-command-line/38749776#38749776

Answer (score 36):

### [`keychain`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/keychain)

solves this in a painless way. It's in the repos for Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install keychain
```

and perhaps for many other distros (it looks like it originated from Gentoo).

This program will start an `ssh-agent` if none is running, and provide shell scripts that can be `source`d and connect the current shell to this particular `ssh-agent`.

For `bash`, with a private key named `id_rsa`, add the following to your `.profile`:

```
keychain --nogui id_rsa
```

This will start an `ssh-agent` and add the `id_rsa` key on the first login after reboot. If the key is passphrase-protected, it will also ask for the passphrase. **No need to use unprotected keys anymore!** For subsequent logins, it will recognize the agent and not ask for a passphrase again.

Also, add the following as a last line of your `.bashrc`:

```
. ~/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
```

This will let the shell know where to reach the SSH agent managed by `keychain`. Make sure that `.bashrc` is sourced from `.profile`.

However, it seems that `cron` jobs still don't see this. As a remedy, include the line above in the `crontab`, just before your actual command:

```
* * * * * . ~/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh; your-actual-command
```

Comment: I do not find it plausible that involving a keychain makes this easier in any reliable way.

Comment: @Dan-Kegel - Actually, what keychain is doing is exactly [netskink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893231/1618452), below.  Except here, you don't have to write the code for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Don't expose your SSH keys without passphrase. Use [ssh-cron](https://github.com/fbb-git/ssh-cron) instead, which allows you to schedule tasks using SSH agents.

Comment: How is this different from the answer above regarding [keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041092/1618452)?  Or the [hard-coded answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893231/1618452) below by netskink?

Comment: It just works out-of-the-box, but underneath, they do basically the same.

Answer (score 3):

So I had a similar problem.  I came here and saw various answers but with some experimentation here is how I got it work with sshkeys with passphrase, ssh-agent and cron.

First off, my ssh setup uses the following script in my bash init script.

```
# JFD Added this for ssh
SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment

    # start the ssh-agent
    function start_agent {
        echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
        # spawn ssh-agent
        /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
        echo succeeded
        chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
        . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
        /usr/bin/ssh-add
    }


    if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
         . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
         ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
            start_agent;
        }
   else
        start_agent;
   fi
```

When I login, I enter my passphrase once and then from then on it will use ssh-agent to authenticate me automatically.

The ssh-agent details are kept in .ssh/environment.  Here is what that script will look like:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-v3Tbd2Hjw3n9/agent.2089; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2091; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
#echo Agent pid 2091;
```

Regarding cron, you can setup a job as a regular user in various ways.
If you run crontab -e as root user it will setup a root user cron.  If you run as crontab -u davis -e it will add a cron job as userid davis.  Likewise, if you run as user davis and do crontab -e it will create a cron job which runs as userid davis.  This can be verified with the following entry:

```
30 *  *   *   *     /usr/bin/whoami
```

This will mail the result of whoami every 30 minutes to user davis. (I did a crontabe -e as user davis.)

If you try to see what keys are used as user davis, do this:

```
36 *  *   *   *     /usr/bin/ssh-add -l
```

It will fail, the log sent by mail will say

```
To: davis@xxxx.net
Subject: Cron <davis@hostyyy> /usr/bin/ssh-add -l

Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

The solution is to source the env script for ssh-agent above.  Here is the resulting cron entry:

```
55 10  *   *   *     . /home/davis/.ssh/environment; /home/davis/bin/domythingwhichusesgit.sh
```

This will run the script at 10:55.  Notice the leading . in the script. It says to run this script in my environment similar to what is in the .bash init script.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply supplying ssh command (whether it's a cron command or in script launched by cron) with private key solved the issue.

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

myscript:

```
...
ssh -i ~/.ssh/<private_key_file> remote_host@remote_ip ...
...
```

No need to install any additional packages or create secondary keys accessible by `crond`

Answer (score -3):

Yesterday I had similar problem...

I have cron job on one server, which start some action on other server, using ssh... Problem was user permissions, and keys...

in crontab I had

```
* * * * * php /path/to/script/doSomeJob.php
```

And it simply didn't work ( didnt have permissions ). 
I tryed to run cron as specific user, which is connected to other server

```
* * * * * user php /path/to/script/doSomeJob.php
```

But with no effect.

Finally, i navicate to script and then execute php file, and it worked..

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/script/; php doSomeJob.php
```