# Git fetch failing in cron. Runs fine manually

Tags: python, git, unix, cron

The entire script runs fine. I will also note that if I copy and paste the cron job into the shell and run it manually it works with no issues.

```
Base = '/home/user/git/'
GIT_out = Base + ("git_file.txt")
FILE_NAME =  Base + 'rules/file.xml'
CD_file =  open(Base + "rules/reports/CD.txt", 'r')


os.chdir(Base + 'rules')
gitFetchPull = "git fetch --all   ;sleep 3 ; git pull --all" 
git1 = subprocess.Popen(gitFetchPull, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
gitOut = git1.stdout.read()
print(gitOut)
```

When I read the output from cron it appears to not be able to authenticate

```
Received disconnect from 172.17.3.18: 2: Too many authentication failures for tyoffe4
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: Could not fetch origin
```

cron job

```
 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/tyoffe4/git/rules/reports/cd_release.py  >/home/tyoffe4/git/rules/reports/cd_release.out 2>&1
```

Comment: what is the git remotes configuration? what transport are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely an issue of the cron environment not having the environment variables set up by your ssh agent. Therefore when git makes an ssh connection, it can't authenticate, because it can't contact your ssh agent and get keys.

This answer probably has what you're looking for:
[ssh-agent and crontab -- is there a good way to get these to meet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205282/ssh-agent-and-crontab-is-there-a-good-way-to-get-these-to-meet)

If for some reason it's not ssh-agent related, try `print os.environ` at the top of your script to dump the value of all environment variables.

Compare the output from cron and running `env` in your bash shell. There are likely some differences, and one of them is the source of your error.

If you set up the same environment variables in  your shell as you have in cron, the behavior should reproduce.